# Task "sass" not found using grunt with PatternLab

Tags: node.js, macos, sass, gruntjs, patternlab.io

Sass is not found when I'm using grunt with PatternLab.

I have Mac El Capitan, and I think Node and Sass are properly setup even though I am still not sure why it cannot find Sass.

I tried to install another version of Node and Sass, but still the same error.

Any ideas?

See below the grunt output:

---

Running "shell:patternlabStyles-rpm" (shell) task
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.

> PatternLabStarter@2.4.0 postinstall /Users/my_user/Projects/my_app/src/global/pattern-lab
>   find node_modules/ -name "*.info" -type f -delete

grunt-scss-lint@0.3.4 node_modules/grunt-scss-lint
└── lodash@2.4.1
Using rainbow 2.0.0
Using sass 3.4.5
Using bundler 1.11.2
Using scss-lint 0.33.0
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 4 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
**Loading "sass.js" tasks...ERROR**
**>> Error: The `libsass` binding was not found in /Users/my_user/Projects/my_app/src/global/pattern-lab/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-46/binding.node**

> > This usually happens because your node version has changed.
> >     Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current node version.
> >     Warning: Task "sass" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

---

**PS:** Concerning the line: "Error: The `libsass` binding was not found in /Users/my_user/Projects/my_app/src/global/pattern-lab/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-46/binding.node", the vendor folder doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix, it was necessary to add the correct node-sass binary where it was expected to be.

The solution was put in practice in [this post](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1162).

> So, manually created folder "darwin-x64-14". Then downloaded equivalent "binding.node" file from 
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries/blob/master/darwin-x64-14_binding.node
>   and copied the file to "darwin-x64-14" folder.